# Shisha Ushmonim Umeya - mi yodeya?

Tags: mi-yodeya-series, number

### Who knows one hundred eighty-six?

*Please cite/link your sources, if possible. At some point at least twenty-four hours from now, I will:*

- *Upvote all interesting answers.*
- *Accept the best answer.*
- *Go on to the next number.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 186 missing sections (simanim) of Orach Chaim in the Baal Hatanya's Shulchan Aruch. (The weight of evidence indicates that all of them were indeed written, but were lost in one of the two fires that burned down his house.)

Answer (score 1):

186 is the gematria of the word מקום, a term for Hashem (because "He is the place of the world, rather than the world being His place" - since He transcends it).

It is also the gematria b'ribua (squared gematria) of the Four-Lettered Name of Hashem: י squared is 100, ה squared is 25, ו squared is 36, ה squared is 25. Total: 186.

Answer (score 1):

*Yosef* died 186 years after *Avraham*.

Answer (score 0):

From the first day of Pesach till and including Simchas Torah there are always 186 days.

Answer (score 0):

186 [are](http://cheshbon.weeklyshtikle.com/2011/09/most-possible-seudos.html#comments) the feasts in a long year.

According to [Shtickler](http://cheshbon.weeklyshtikle.com), the most possible mandated Shabbat/holiday meals in a year is when, like the year we conclude today, the year is a leap year and has its holidays all on weekdays.